# How can concat two Integers in a TextView using Databinding?

Tags: android, textview, android-databinding, android-mvvm

I have a ViewModel with the next variables:

```
public MutableLiveData<Integer> questionPosition = new MutableLiveData<>();
public MutableLiveData<Integer> totalQuestions = new MutableLiveData<>();
```

And I want show it in a TextView like `questionPosition/totalQuestions` (this is not a division)

```
android:text='@={examViewModel.questionPosition + "/" + examViewModel.totalQuestions}'
```

But in the two cases fail.

How can do it?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The problem was that I had not to initialize the ViewModel in the Activity, but the code of the question work too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

in String.xml

```
<string name="output"> %1$s / %2$s </string>
```

in you xml file

```
android:text="@{@string/output(examViewModel.questionPosition, examViewModel.totalQuestions)}"
```